# Omniauth facebook, github, google login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Hello I'm new to rails

I have used omniauth gem to establish a login with Gmail, Facebook, and Github.

I am unable to logout from my webpage.

For logout, I have used this command for logout

```
<%= link_to  "Sign-out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-outline-danger ", type:"button" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Omniauth login is working? What gems are you integrating? What is your error?

Make sure you have `config.sign_out_via = :delete` in `/config/initializers/devise.rb`. If it isn't so, uncomment this line and restart the server, then check again.